# UICollectionViewCell alpha not changing when using '.reloadItems'

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been using `UICollectionView.reloadData()` to update my cells on the fly and this has worked perfectly, although, it causes the animation to be extremely clunky. I hook into `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` and perform logic to determine the cells UI.

Here is that methods code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RepCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RepCollectionViewCell

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: cell.bounds.midX, y: cell.bounds.midY),
                                radius: cell.bounds.width / 2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)

        path.close()

        mask.frame = cell.bounds
        mask.path = path.cgPath

        var alpha = 1.0
        var color = UIColor.white
        var size = 0.0

        switch reps[indexPath.row] {
        case currentRep + 3:
            size = FONT_SIZE / 4
        case currentRep + 2:
            size = FONT_SIZE / 3
        case currentRep + 1:
            size = FONT_SIZE / 2
        case currentRep:
            color = .green
            size = FONT_SIZE
        case currentRep - 1:
            size = FONT_SIZE / 2
            alpha = 0.75
        case currentRep - 2:
            size = FONT_SIZE / 3
            alpha = 0.50
        case currentRep - 3:
            size = FONT_SIZE / 4
            alpha = 0.25
        default:
            color = .clear
            alpha = 0
        }

        cell.layer.mask = mask
        cell.repCount.text = String(reps[indexPath.row])
        cell.backgroundColor = color
        cell.repCount.font = UIFont(name: FONT_NAME, size: CGFloat(size))
        cell.alpha = CGFloat(alpha)

        return cell
    }
```

Now as mentioned the alpha is set correctly when using `UICollectionView.reloadData()` but, when I use the `UICollectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPaths])` method and pass an array of indexPaths, the cells alpha does not update. However, the background colour, font size, contentView alpha etc... will update.

Here is the code I am using to generate the indexPaths of the cells that need to be updated and the subsequent call.

```
private func focusCollectionView()
    {
        self.MyUICollectionView.reloadItems(at: generateIndexPaths())
        self.MyUICollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: myVar - 1, section: 0), at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }

    private func generateIndexPaths() -> [IndexPath]
    {
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

        if(myVar - 4 >= 0)
        {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar - 4, section: 0))
        }
        if(myVar - 3 >= 0)
        {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar - 3, section: 0))
        }
        if(myVar - 2 >= 0)
        {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar - 2, section: 0))
        }
        if(myVar - 1 >= 0)
        {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar - 1, section: 0))
        }

        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar, section: 0))

        if(myVar + 1 < _myOtherVar)
        {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar + 1, section: 0))
        }
        if(myVar + 2 < _myOtherVar)
        {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar + 2, section: 0))
        }
        if(myVar + 3 < _myOtherVar)
        {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: myVar + 3, section: 0))
        }

        return indexPaths
    }
```

Here is a demo of the two results, the first using 'reloadData'and the second using 'reloadItems': https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQgXJ.jpg

I do not know why this is occurring and what to do to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: Question that may help debug, did you override the prepareForReuse method in your MyUICollectionViewCell class?

Comment: @strwils I have not, is it best practice to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood the background color should show through? Or did I misunderstood the intention?

So testing with your code it seems alpha for the cell is not applied, see

[image: view]

**Idea**

Setting the backgroundColor of the cell to .clear would allow us to use the alpha of the contentView and we could still see the background through.

**To Test it**

In UICollectionViewController subclass I used:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .black
```

I slightly modified your code here (like suggested by rmaddy in his answer):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
...
cell.myLabel.text = String(reps[indexPath.row])
cell.contentView.alpha = 1
...
```

Then changed each

- `cell.backgroundColor =` to `cell.contentView.backgroundColor =`
- `cell.alpha =` to `cell.contentView.alpha =`

In MyUICollectionViewCell I set the backgroundColor of the cell to UIColor.clear:

```
self.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Besides that, the code for the CollectionViewCell is rather uninteressting, here just for reference:

```
class MyUICollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let myLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.myLabel)
        self.myLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.myLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

In my test case myVar is the index of the selected item, so I removed the -1 in scrollToItem, so that it looks like this:

```
private func focusCollectionView()
{
    self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: generateIndexPaths())
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(
        at: IndexPath(item: myVar, section: 0),
        at: .centeredHorizontally,
        animated: true)
}
```

**Demo**

So when testing it in the simulator it looks like this:

[image: Testing in Simulator]

Is this what you were looking for?